# How to set default inner serializer data in django-rest?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two simple serializers

```
class UserSerializer(Serializer);
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='Mile')
    age =  serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=25)

class AccountSerializer(Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid4())
    user = UserSerializer()
```

And i want to set the default user in AccountSerializer if it is not specified.
For example,

```
account = AccountSerializer(data={'account_id': uuid.UUID('e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1')})
account.is_valid()
account.data


  {
    'account_id': 'e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1',
    'user': {
        'name': 'Mike',                              # user must be default
        'age': 25
    }
}
```

And i also want to set my own values in 'user fields' and leave the other fields by default
For example,

```
account = AccountSerializer(data={'account_id': uuid.UUID('e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1'),
                                   'user': {'name': 'Julie'}})
    account.is_valid()
    account.data

{
        'account_id': 'e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1',
        'user': {
            'name': 'Julie',                              # user name must be 'Julie' but age by default
            'age': 25
        }
    }
```

How should i implement this? Please note that I am not going to save the model to the database! I just need to check the incoming json and set the fields to default if not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set direct `default` in serializer, and call `serializer.validated_data` in last. It will keep data in your request, or auto fill default if dont have

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer);
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='Mike') #you want default is Mike?
    age =  serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=25)

class AccountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid.UUID('e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1')) #this is your default uuid user
    user = UserSerializer(required=False, default={
    'name': 'Mike',
    'age': 25
})
```

**if you want more custom for handle special logic in validate**. You can try override `validate`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    age = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def validate_name(self, value):
        if not value:
            return 'Mike' #default name, or anything logic you want
        return value

    def validate_age(self, value):
        if not value:
            return 25 #default age
        return value

class AccountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)
    user = UserSerializer()

    def validate_account_id(self, value):
        if not value:
            return uuid.UUID('e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1')
        return value
```

After this, you call

```
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
print(serializer.validated_data)
```

`serializer.validated_data` will have data you want.

Comment: Please tell me if I need to use a serializer at all if I'm not going to save the model? I need to get data from the client, convert it to correct json (the json that the service needs) validate it and send a "post" request to the service. 
If the client did not specify required fields, then i need to fill them in with default values

Comment: `serializers.Serializer` is custom serializer, it not mapping with any model, and not save to database.
It use for validate, and if valid, send this or doing whatever you want

Comment: But this very bad implemenation. What if I have not 2 fields but 100 or 200? Do I have to implement 'if-condition' for each field? All fields may be optional.

Comment: you can set direct `default` inside serializer. In this line default=25
`age =  serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=25)`. Override `validate` for case you want doing special logic

Comment: Your solution doesn't work correctly. For example, AccountSerializer(data={}).later it will return {'account_id': 'e623429d-b1d1-4238-91b8-03e6f5ec58f1'}. But 'user' should be set by default

Comment: i updated my answer, can you check again?

Comment: Do you think it is a bad idea to validate data from the user using serializers, set default values ​​to then convert it to canonical json and send json to the service? Maybe a better way to use json schema?

Comment: Better you can ask it in other question. This comment not for discuss so far from your first question.

Comment: yeah, my solution answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you don't have a model

1.serializer.py
'''

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='Mile')
    age = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=25) #if key age is missing, value of age become 25

    def validate(self,data):
        #other wise you can set default value of age here,
        if data.get('name',None) is None: #this conditon will be true only when name = serializer.CharField(required=False)
            data['name']='Mike'
        if data.get('age',None)is None: #this conditon will be true only when age = serializer.IntergerField(required=False)
                data['age']=25  
        return data
```

'''
views.py
'''

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={'name': 'cc', 'age': 14})
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.validated_data
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'cc', 'age': 14}
```

'''
or if you miss specifying age in views.py
'''

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={'name': 'cc'})
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.validated_data
# { 'name': 'cc', 'age': 25}
```

'''

Comment: But I need completely different. I need to provide incomplete information in AccountSerializer.  And if the user is not defined there, then set the default user.